# Set up a linked server to Sybase (from SQL Server Management Studio)

Tags: sql-server-2012, sybase, linked-server

I've given a task to import data from Sybase to SQL server 2012, and I figured that the easiest way for me (I am a beginner) to do this is to set up a linked server from SQL server to the Sybase and import data from there.

The Sybase and the SQL server are not on the same computer, but I can remote-access to either one from my computer just fine. I am having a difficulty in trying to set up a link in between these two, though, and I would greatly appreciate any help.

On the Sybase, the System DSN only has SQL Anywhere 12 CustDB right now. Can this work as the ODBC driver, or do I have to install a Sybase ODBC driver?

Also, I have not come across from my research yet, but is there a way to import data from Sybase to SQL server just by using a SQL script? I understand if there were, it would probably be out of my league, but still...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sybase ASE, Sybase IQ and Sybase SQL Anywhere are different products so you will need to install the correct ODBC driver depending on what the target Sybase database is actually running as this was not mentioned in your question.

In terms of exporting/importing data you can use the bcp  too to export/import data from the command line (this utility is available for both Sybase and MS SQL), but you just need to be cautious regarding character set differences between the Sybase and MSSQL instances. For example the default Sybase out of the box install is binary case-sensitive whereas MSSQL is often installed as case-insensitive.

Comment: I have the SQL Anywhere 12. Which ODBC driver does the SQL Anywhere 12 need? I will also Google for it, but still...

Comment: I've never used SQL Anywhere but 12 is a pretty old version - 16 ODBC info here http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbprogramming/odbc-driver-deploy.html which has some details.

Also bear in mind that for a linked server you'll need to install the drive on the MSSQL database host so that the instance can connect to the Sybase database.